# C++ How to draw letter same size

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, directx

I'm working on my edit box that I'm creating.  I need to find a font that draw letter at same size.  I'm using directx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that by "find a font that draw letter at same size" you mean a font where all of the letters are the same size. This is called a Monospaced or Fixed Width Font. There should be several on most systems, the one that you should be able to count on always existing on Windows systems is "Courier New".

Comment: there are also terminal fonts, however, if your after appearance, you'd need to trawl through a font library to find a fixed width that looks good, maybe LetterGothic would do